# Prove $\left|\int_{a}^b f(t)dt \right| \leq \int_{a}^b \left|f(t)\right|dt$

Tags: calculus

> Prove that if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then $$\left|\int_{a}^b f(t)dt \right| \leq \int_{a}^b \left|f(t)\right|dt.$$

Since $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, so is $\left|f\right|$. Therefore  since $\left|f\right| \geq f$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, we have $$\int_{a}^b f(t) dt\leq \int_{a}^b \left |f\right|dt.$$ I am not sure how to use this to prove the result. Also why must $f$ be integrable?

Comment: The answer depends on a few things. By "integrable" do you mean Riemann or Lebesgue integrable?\

Comment: @UmbertoP. Riemann Integrable.

Comment: Considering the question, I don't think he is even aware of the concept *Lebesgue Integrable*.

Comment: @Puzzled417 look at RRL's answer. Recall that $|a| \le b$ if and only if $-b \le a \le b$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. If $f$ weren't integrable, when would this not be true?

Comment: It wouldn't be true because the integral of $f$ would be undefined. If you don't mind a flippant response, is it true that $\text{blue} \le 2$?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$-|f(t)| \leqslant f(t) \leqslant |f(t)|,$$

and

$$g(t) \leqslant h(t) \implies \int_a^b g \leqslant \int_a^b h$$

Comment: The downvotes on this answer make no sense.

Comment: OP has already concluded $\int_{a}^b f(t) dt\leq \int_{a}^b \left |f\right|dt.$

Comment: Correct, but OP need to conclude more.

Comment: @D1X. Yes and how does one then prove $|\int f| \leqslant \int |f|$

Comment: @UmbertoP.: Thanks for comment.

Comment: And now the downvotes have been rescinded.